# Resetting Application iPhone App

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to reset an application so that it runs as if it hasn't been opened yet without exiting the app?

I'm making a game and when you complete all the levels and get back to the main menu and start again, it thinks you have already completed all the levels already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact details depend on the application but, basically, this is why having the "M" in "MVC" (a data model) as a separate layer is a good idea.  You write a method that sets your entire model into a starting state and call it when you want to reset everything.

Once that's done, go back to your menu (the way to "go back" depends on how you've added levels) and it's a fresh start.

Comment: Nobody can without knowing all of the state/data that your app uses.

Comment: Well what do you mean by starting state?

Comment: All the values that your application-specific data has when the app starts.